# CSS: On mobile, article skips/jumps/moves when scrolling

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

When browsing the following code on mobile (Android, Chrome, Full HD screen, portrait), the lorem ipsum-text and its heading ("Home") seem to 'skip' slightly when scrolling. More precisely, it seems that the article element gets stretched to the bottom right, by about 10px.

I have read about this problem and there seems to exist a fix where you'd somehow disable hardware accelerated scrolling (which seems to cause this problem) with Javascript.

The issue: I may only use HTML5 and CSS3 for this project.

Is this fixable with only these two languages?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="author" content="John Smith">
    <meta name="description" content="A website.">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Header H1</h1>
        <h2>Header H2</h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/dir" class="nav-item" id="current-page">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/dir/page1" class="nav-item">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/dir/page2" class="nav-item">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/dir/page3" class="nav-item">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
        <h3>Home</h3>
        <section>   
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque elementum pulvinar ante, ac feugiat augue gravida eget. </p>
            <p>Vestibulum a odio iaculis, sagittis arcu vitae, elementum orci. Quisque et pretium mauris. Vivamus auctor ultricies lacus at efficitur.</p>
            <p>Nullam fermentum dui et ligula placerat faucibus. Curabitur ut libero nec erat finibus ornare. Suspendisse convallis imperdiet consequat. </p>
            <p>Vestibulum a odio iaculis, sagittis arcu vitae, elementum orci. Quisque et pretium mauris. Vivamus auctor ultricies lacus at efficitur.</p>
            <p>Nullam fermentum dui et ligula placerat faucibus. Curabitur ut libero nec erat finibus ornare. Suspendisse convallis imperdiet consequat. </p>
            <p>Vestibulum a odio iaculis, sagittis arcu vitae, elementum orci. Quisque et pretium mauris. Vivamus auctor ultricies lacus at efficitur.</p>
            <p>Nullam fermentum dui et ligula placerat faucibus. Curabitur ut libero nec erat finibus ornare. Suspendisse convallis imperdiet consequat. </p>
        </section>
    </article>
    <footer>
        &copy; John Smith 2015 <br>
        <small><em>Some small-emmed text.</em></small> <br>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
background-color:#fbffff;
padding-top:2vh;
padding-bottom:2vh;
}

body {
font-family:Merriweather, sans-serif;
overflow:auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:#E3DEC1;
margin:0 auto;
padding:.1vh 0 0;
}

header {
line-height:50%;
}

#current-page {
color:#451b16;
}

header h1,header h2 {
color:#B94629;
}

a,a:visited {
color:#47AFAF;
}

nav > ul > li > a:visited,.nav-item {
color:#FFF;
}

nav {
background-color:#B94629;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}

nav ul {
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
display:inline;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
display:block;
line-height:50px;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0 24px;
}

nav > ul > li > a:hover {
color:#e89f65;
}

h3 {
padding-bottom:2vh;
text-align:justify;
border-bottom:1px grey solid;
display:block;
margin:5vh 6vh 0;
}

section {
padding:0 6vh 4vh;
}

footer {
background-color:#dfd9b9;
padding:1vh 0;
}

p {
font-size:12pt;
line-height:20pt;
letter-spacing:.1pt;
text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: I think you _want_ hardware accelerated scrolling. This stuff should mean there are _no_ jumps. So try to add `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` to enable it on the element that has the issue.

Comment: Alas, this does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself. This had nothing to do with hardware acceleration of the phone.

In the above stylesheet, pretty much every element was sized using viewport height. When scrolling on a mobile phone using Chrome, the viewport height somehow changes after scrolling, therefore changing the size of any element styled with `vh`.

I changed every `vh` to `vw`, because the viewport width does not change when scrolling vertically. This fixed the issue and browsing on mobile now works like a charm.

As a precaution, I disabled horizontal scrolling (`overflow-x: hidden`) so `vw` will never change on the same device.